# PHP Reading XML Response After Posting Data To External Server

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I am new to php an XML. Plus I have gone through many threads on this topic here.

There might be a slight glitch, but I am not able to read this.

### Here is what I am doing to read it as per one of the threads.

```
        //parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
        $returnxml = simplexml_load_string($result);

        if ($returnxml === false) {
            die('Error parsing Return XML');
        }

        //now we can loop through the xml structure
        foreach ($returnxml->channel->item as $item) {
            print $item->title;
        }
```

### I do not get anything using above code

### Here is the actual [EXACT] XML response using CURL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
&lt;ncresponse

orderID="120130414021640"

PAYID="BESALDOM 516A65F5E5E"

STATUS="4"

NCSTATUS="0"

NCERROR=""

NCERRORPLUS="Your transaction has been submitted for processing."

ACCEPTANCE="BINF-"

IPCTY=""

CCCTY=""

IDUsager="7884TSMA"

/&gt;
```

---

### Next this is the CURL Code I am using, which looks fairly ok.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $this->omnipayment_action_url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($myorder));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $flds);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

---

Thanks in advance, any help will be much appreciated...

Comment: The return xml is one node and you trying to loop it using `$returnxml->channel` - where do you see in the response channel ?

Comment: @aditi : I have no idea what you are saying. I just want to read this particular xml.

Comment: please double check the formatting of the part you call the exact curl response. Make yourself comfortable with the editing tools a bit more, in the current form how your question is, it's not really clear if that is XML or not or what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451396/adidi) rightly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997851/php-reading-xml-response-after-posting-data-to-external-server/15997957#comment22811400_15997851), you're not trying to obtain the information supplied to you from the right location. The information you need is in the root node and stored as [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), here's a quick example showing how to get those:-

```
<?php
function parse_response($response) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($xml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        $arr[(string)$key] = (string)$value;
    }
    return $arr;
}

var_dump(parse_response($str));
/*
    array(10) {
      ["orderID"]=>
      string(15) "120130414021640"
      ["PAYID"]=>
      string(20) "BESALDOM 516A65F5E5E"
      ["STATUS"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["NCSTATUS"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["NCERROR"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["NCERRORPLUS"]=>
      string(51) "Your transaction has been submitted for processing."
      ["ACCEPTANCE"]=>
      string(5) "BINF-"
      ["IPCTY"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["CCCTY"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["IDUsager"]=>
      string(8) "7884TSMA"
    }
*/
```

Comment: It does work, try harder. Are you obtaining the response as a string and passing it into the `parse_response` function?

Comment: I am passing whatever CURL responded back with in $result. I did not add any conversion function. Next I tried to use your function as is and it does not even dump anything like your example does.

Comment: Finally it worked. The response was not even an xml. I read it like string and the results came in. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

simple load xml file ..

```
<?php
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($result);

$status = (string)$xml->Status; 
$operator_trans_id = (string)$xml->OPID;
$trns_id = (string)$xml->TID;
```

Comment: use response which is returned by Curl function